# При редактировании сниппета ошибочно показывается предупреждение о необходимости дополнить ссылку на CodePen кодом

Tags: дефект, сниппеты

При редактировании вопроса "[Как организовать навигацию вперед и назад по галерее на jQuery?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/692986/13336)" столкнулся со следующей ошибкой:

Я удалил код автора и начал перенос кода из CodePen в сниппет. Как только сниппет был готов, я нажал <kbd>Привести в порядок</kbd>, затем снял галку <kbd>Показать консоль</kbd> и выбрал <kbd>Скрыть код по умолчанию</kbd>.

После этих манипуляций, готовый сниппет оказался ниже прямой ссылки на CodePen и я получил предупреждение о том, что каждая такая ссылка должна сопровождаться примером кода.

Это явная ошибка. К сожалению, сразу сделать скриншот я не догадался, а ошибка пропала, когда я нажал <kbd>редактировать пример кода</kbd> и сохранил сниппет без изменений.